# Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Tags: php, mysqli

I have tried to follow the advice given in - how-to-perform-update-with-mysqli-prepare?  on the site but am having no luck.

The following:

```
<?php

//connection
$con = new mysqli ("localhost","user","password","db");

$playno = "22";
$n1 = "4";
$n2 = "4";
$n3 = "4";

$stmt = $con -> prepare("UPDATE game SET no1 = ?, no2 = ?, no3 = ? WHERE id = ?");

$stmt -> bind_param ('iiii',"$n1","$n2","$n3","$playno");
$stmt -> execute();


?>
```

Gives this in the browser:

> Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in
> C:\xampp\htdocs... on line 13

Answer (score 2):

```
$stmt -> bind_param ('iiii',$n1,$n2,$n3,$playno);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the 2nd argument in `bind_param` is expected to be a reference to a variable.

```
$stmt -> bind_param ('iiii',"$n1","$n2","$n3","$playno");
```

From [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

> Note that mysqli_stmt_bind_param() requires parameters to be passed by
>   reference

It's should be: `$stmt -> bind_param ('iiii',$n1,$n2,$n3,$playno);`

Answer (score 0):

When you try to pass the params as follows

```
$stmt -> bind_param ('iiii',"$n1","$n2","$n3","$playno");
```

the `"$n1"` etc. are treated as constant strings, and hence leads to the **error**(and not warning).

Also, you need to pass integral values and not strings.

```
$stmt -> bind_param( 'iiii',$n1, $n2, $n3, $playno );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt -> bind_param ('iiii',"$n1","$n2","$n3","$playno");
```

should be

```
$stmt -> bind_param ('ssss',$n1,$n2,$n3,$playno);
```

or

```
$playno = 22;
$n1 = 4;
$n2 = 4;
$n3 = 4;

$stmt -> bind_param ('iiii',$n1,$n2,$n3,$playno);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem it's simple:

This is a string
    $playno = "22"; //string
    $n1 = "4"; //string
    $n2 = "4"; //string
    $n3 = "4"; //string

```
$stmt = $con -> prepare("UPDATE game SET no1 = ?, no2 = ?, no3 = ? WHERE id = ?");
```

Here your mistake
    $stmt -> bind_param ('iiii',"$n1","$n2","$n3","$playno"); //fail, You must use s
    $stmt -> bind_param ('ssss',$n1,$n2,$n3,$playno); //this is correct

or change:

```
$playno = 22; //integer
$n1 = 4; //integer
$n2 = 4; //integer
$n3 = 4; //integer
$stmt -> bind_param ('iiii',$n1,$n2,$n3,$playno); //this is correct
```

and then:

```
$stmt -> execute();
```